# Ошибка в bios нажмите F1

Tags: bios

При включении компьютера возникает ошибка (картинка ниже). Не помогает, даже если принудительно в bios отключаю опцию "при возникновении ошибки F1...", т.к. все мои настройки bios пропадают.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данную проблему?
[image: ошибка в bios]

Comment: Заменить батарейку для начала

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov оформите в виде ответа это, с пояснением почему могут пропадать настройки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С большой вероятностью у Вас села батарейка BIOS, поэтому при отключении питания настройки пропадают т.к. батарейка служит именно для хранения настроек BIOS.

Кроме того каждый BIOS устроен по разному, поэтому возможно именно на Вашей материнской плате настройки пропадают даже при перезагрузке.

Как заменить батарейку писать не буду - мануалов по этой теме предостаточно, даже с видео.

Однако, если не поможет замена батарейки, попробуйте обновить BIOS, но это уже немного другая история.

Comment: Если замена батарейки помогает только на время (например от недели до месяца) то это говорит о неисправности материнской платы.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @freeasy - если помогло, отметьте ответ как правильный.